# Decimal representation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I need to prove that, given ${a,n}$ integers with $a<10^n$, $\frac a {10^n}$ has two different decimal representations.

I know that this is related to the fact that $0,99999... =1$, and I know how to prove that using series convergence, but I'm having trouble putting togheter a decent proof for the statement aforementioned.

If somebody could give me a hint, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I take it $n$ is $k$. But look: can you find *one* decimal representation for $a/10^k$? If you can find one, I bet you can find two.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My mistake. I´m not quite sure what do you mean. Sure I can find one, I just construct a sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n} {10^n}$, which converges to the number that I want. What do I win with that?

Comment: OK, let's look at something simpler. Find a decimal representation for $187625343/10^4$. Do you really need an infinite series for that?

Comment: No, but using series was the only ´formal´ way I came up with to justify the fact that there is at least one decimal representation... I may be complicating this way to much

Comment: I think so. The decimal representation of $a/10^n$ just isn't that hard, especially if you start with the decimal representation of $a$.

Comment: Ok, so I have one decimal representation. How do I get the other?

Comment: Well, what is that one decimal representation that you have?

Comment: I just shift the number to the right. Then what? I take (a-1), shift it to the right and write 9s instead of 0s? I am terribly sorry if it's difficult to understand me, I'm Spanish so this is in no way my first language...

Comment: You've got it --- muy bueno!

Answer (score 1):

The restriction $a<10^n$ is unnecessary if we allow digits before the decimal point. Assume the claim is false, then among all counterexmples there is one with minimal possible $n$. If $n>0$ then $\frac{10a}{10^n}=\frac a{10^{n-1}}$ also has two representations (obtained from those for $\frac a{10^n}$ by shifting left. Therefore $n=0$ and $\frac an=a$ is an integer. These have obviously two representations $a+0.00000\ldots$ and $(a-1)+0.99999\ldots$.

Comment: But, aren't you assuming that there is at least one $n$ greater than zero that allows two different representations?